# Panic Transmit 5 cache is not cleared

Tags: macos, ftp, sftp

With Panic Transmit 5.10.4 the contents of ~/Library/Caches/Transmit/ is over 5GB. I use BBEdit as an external editor, files I edit are never purged / cleared. Even after macOS restart

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The only reference to caching from the support pages is that quicklook is intended to cache files locally and this is something with a warning attached.

> Remote files will be downloaded to a cache folder first, so be careful using Quick Look on large files.

https://help.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/menus/#quick-look

If you can't get the cache to shrink when you [change back to using the internal editor](https://help.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/editing-files/) and then re-edit a file you see in the cache, I would open a support ticket with Panic. They are exceptionally good at supporting their product and if you link here in the request, they can see what we're making of their documentation and maybe tweak it if we're not seeing their information needed to run the tool efficiently.

Also, I would mention in their support if you previously had an [older version of Transmit 5 installed and used the Transmit Disk feature](https://help.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/transmit-disk/) and then upgraded past the version when that was no longer supported.

Comment: Many thanks Mike!